# MATLAB change elements to zero based on surrounding data

Tags: matlab, matrix, nearest-neighbor

Just a matrix question that's possibly simple that I can't figure out. Say I have a 20 x 20 matrix A. I have another matrix B that is the same size but logical. I'd like any element in A that's position is within (say) 3 of a '1' in B, to be changed to 0.

James

Comment: How do you measure distance between matrix elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image processing toolbox includes a function `imdilate` that can fill in the positions of `B` near `1`s to also be `1`s. Then we just use logical indexing for `A`. The distance you mentioned is computed using euclidean distance. If you want chessboard distance, use `neighborhood = ones(2*R+1)` instead.

```
R = 3;
[X,Y] = ndgrid(-ceil(R):ceil(R));
neighborhood = (X.^2 + Y.^2)<=R^2;
A(imdilate(B,neighborhood)) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

**[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** based approach to solve such a problem -

```
%// Form random A and B for demo purposes
N = 50;            %// input datasize
A = rand(N);
B = rand(N)>0.9;
R = 2;             %// neighbourhood radius

%// Find linear indices offsets within 2R*2R neighbourhood
offset_displacement = bsxfun(@plus,(-R:R)',[-R:R]*size(A,1)); %//'
offset_matches = bsxfun(@plus,(-R:R)'.^2,[-R:R].^2) <= R*R;   %//'
offset_matched_displacement = offset_displacement(offset_matches);

%// Use those offsets to find actual linear indices for all '1' points in B
loc = bsxfun(@plus,find(B),offset_matched_displacement');             %//'

%// Set "eligible" points (based on loc) to zeros in A
A(loc(loc>=1 & loc<=numel(A)))=0;
```

**Debugging input & output -**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Matlab is always praised for its toolboxes, when in fact all you need is `bsxfun`. :-)

Comment: @knedlsepp That's exactly what I tell others! Actually for this problem `conv2` might be the most efficient one, because even with this `bsxfun`, there are multiple overwrites!

Comment: Oh right, just tested it. Up to N=500 `conv2` beats `imdilate`. Based on all your answers up to now, one could possibly combine a free version of the image processing toolbox with comparable speed. :-)

Comment: @knedlsepp Yeah I thought so! `imdilate` is known to be slow at times.